# Generics with the JavaFX 2 TableViewBuilder using differing TableColumn types

Tags: javafx-2

Suppose I want to use Generics with the TableViewBuilder. The following works, but
I'm getting a type safety warning from the .columns invocation. It automatically
creates an array of type `TableColumn<Thing,?>`

```
TableColumn<Thing, Integer> anIntColumn = ... 
TableColumn<Thing, Double> aDoubleColumn = ... 
TableColumn<Thing, String> aStringColumn = ... 
TableView<Thing> table =
                TableViewBuilder
                        .<Thing> create()
                        .items(tableDataList)
                        .columns(anIntColumn, aDoubleColumn, aStringColumn).build();
```

Is there some syntax that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use TableViewBuilder and other Builders - they are [deprecated](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2013-March/006725.html) and may not work correctly in future Java versions such as Java 8.

Comment: Doctor, it hurts when I do this. So don't do this. :) The problem is, I get the same problem with table.getColumns().addAll(c1,c2,c3 etc.

Comment: Create a new question with the [sscce](http://sscce.org/) for the source (which does not use builders) which produces the same issue warning and I'm sure somebody will be able to tell you how to eliminate the warnings.

Comment: Using add(aSingleColumn) instead of addAll(col1, col2) removes the warnings. PS thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not use builders as `jewelsea` already suggested, adding to the performance issues you have you cannot infer any generics to them. The result of `.build()` is always of `<Object, Object>`. A possibility would be to use casts.
2. Make use of FXML if you have the possibilites.
3. If you need code, you can do something like this

.

```
final TableView<Boolean> table = new TableView<Boolean>();
final TableColumn<Boolean, String> col = new TableColumn<Boolean, String>();
table.getColumns().add(col);
```